# return value of program execute from another program

Tags: c, linux, process

My code (call CheckProg.c) need to run (execute) the program "prog.c".

with the next command:

```
return_val = execlp("/bin/prog.c",my_args);
```

"prog.c" have to return the value 14.

I am writing my code in c and compile with LINUX gcc. My question is how to get the return value?

thanks!

Comment: Err, you can't execute `.c` files that contain C source code. You'll need to compile them first.

Comment: Also, you can't get the return value of the `exec...()`d process from within the process calling `exec...()`. If `exec...()` succeeds, the original process no longer exists. The parent that called the original process (e.g. your shell or whatever) can retrieve the return code in the usual ways, however.